# R environment issues when creating a package

Tags: r, package

Let's say I have a function that initializing a new environment:

```
init <-function()
{
    e <- new.env()
}
```

Also, the `init` function lives in another .R file

Then, after it is initialized, I want to start using it in other function calls in different files like

```
init.main <- function(e)
{
    e$data <- list()
    e$number <- 0
}
```

However, this will throw an error saying object `e` is not found. I presume this is because `e` is only locally initialized, but if I were to use a package that relies solely on function calls, how would I get  the functions to be able to talk to each other and use the same environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method.

```r
init <- local({
  e <- NULL
  function() {
    e <<- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
  }
})
init.main <- function() {
  e <- get("e", envir = environment(init))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on whether you want just one `e` or you want to be able to have multiple environments with different contents.

In the first case, simply define `e` at the top level in your package, and have your `init` function modify that copy.  For example,

```
e <- new.env()
init <- function() {
  e <<- new.env()
}
```

Then any other function in your package can see `e` and use it.  Calling `init()` will wipe out any previous contents and set it to empty.

The other case is a little harder, just because you'll need to handle several functions with the same name that refer to different `e` values.  There's an example of this in section 10.7 of the Introduction to R manual that ships with R.